# PerformClick on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have use until now a methods for click button after i have click another button. (i click button "A" and it actives the button "B")

```
buttonDeleteFields.PerformClick();
```

Now, because I innovated design, i have replace this button with a icon (picturebox), but the method PerformClick, with a PictureBox, doesn't work. Can you give me a method that will resolve this problem?
( I click button "A" and it active the picturebox "B")

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?  It gets focus?  The `MouseClick` event handler runs?  Visibility changes?  Something else?  BTW "active" is not a verb, there is "activate" but that still is not clear enough.

Comment: You really don't need `PerformClick()`. If you have code in the `Click` handler, move that code to a method, so you can call that method from anywhere you need it. That's all. Also, Buttons support Images: you can fill one with an Image, or paint it. Many options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the method bound to the `PictureBox.Click` event in method `button1_Click`.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("123");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1_Click(this.pictureBox1, e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To fully emulate the Click event (as if the user has clicked the picture box),

Add these to your form class:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
private int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
```

And call like this inside your button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // OLD CODE: Used to perform click on button 2,
    // before it was changed to a picture box
    // buttonDeleteFields.PerformClick();

    // new code, emulating picture box click:
    SendMessage(pictureBoxDeleteFields.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 1);
    SendMessage(pictureBoxDeleteFields.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Really? You scared the OP by this. Make it simple mate.

Comment: Ok, but how? This is what the OP wants. I could have told him to call the event handler method directly, of course.

Comment: What I meant, don't give a nice but advanced solution like this for a _Hello World_ level. The best is not always the best to suggest. :) Nice coder by the way.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you are right. :) Maybe let him try to grasp this. Pushing your limits is the best way of achieving progress.

Comment: True. You got me in this one.